# MongoDB connecting to authenticationdatabase using shell command

Tags: mongodb, shell, mongo-shell

When i connect using from the OS shell,

```
mongo --port 27017 -u "testusr" -p "testpwd"  --authenticationDatabase "testdb"
```

Instead of switching taking me to testdb, it always logs me into test database?
What I am missing here?

`db.auth("testusr","testpwd")` is working wihtout any authentication issues?
How do I redirect to the correct database?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following works for me

```
mongo localhost:27017/testdb -u "user" -p "pass"  --authenticationDatabase "testdb"
```

You can find help(i used in linux)

```
mongo --help
usage: mongo [options] [db address] [file names (ending in .js)]
db address can be:
foo                   foo database on local machine
192.169.0.5/foo       foo database on 192.168.0.5 machine
192.169.0.5:9999/foo  foo database on 192.168.0.5 machine on port 9999
```